# About an estimate of theorem 3 in Chapter 12 of Evans' book

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is the proof of theorem 3 in Chapter 12 of Evans' book as the following picture. I really don't understand why $|F(Du,u_t,u)|\le C(|Du|+|u_t|+|u|)$, because he didn't give us any restriction on $f$. why just according to $f(0,0,0)=0$ and $u$ is smooth we could derive this estimate? Thanks!

[image: the proof of theorem 3 in Chapter 12 of Evans' book]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following statement, which does not involve any PDE:  this is  multivariable calculus only.

> If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$ smooth and $f(0,0,0)=0$, then for every $R>0$ there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(z)|\le C|z|$ whenever $|z|\le R$.

Proof: by the mean-value inequality we have $|f(z)-f(0)|\le |z|\sup_{|\xi|<R} |Df(\xi)|$, which yields the claim. $\quad \Box$

In your situation the argument of $f$ is  $z=(Du,u_t,u)$. This triple is bounded by the smoothness of $u$; see the line where Evans  refers to its $L^\infty$ norm. This gives $R$, and the aforementioned fact gives $C$.

Comment: Yes, I also thunk about this firstly. But as I said above he didn't give us any restriction on $f$, so we don't know $f \in C^1$. I think it might be a mistake because in the next section, he required $f$ is Lipschitz, but here he didn't require any continues condition. and thank you again.

Comment: I just read the next sections and find he required $f$ is continues in section 12.2.2. I think he might require this condition in theorem 3, too and perhaps just forget to mention it in this theorem. Otherwise, I can't imagine this result is correct.

Comment: @chuck $f$ being Lipschitz would be enough. Knowing the emphasis of Evans' book, I would be very surprised if he considered some nonsmooth energy functionals in there; he tries hard not to obscure ideas with technical details.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers! I understand now.